# Increasing num of layers in LSTM increases the input dimensions in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, lstm

This is my LSTM model and I am finding a peculiar problem while training it.

```
class LSTM1(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_classes, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, seq_length,drop_prob=0.0):
    super(LSTM1, self).__init__()
    self.num_classes = num_classes #number of classes
    self.num_layers = num_layers #number of layers
    self.input_size = input_size #input size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size #hidden state
    self.seq_length = seq_length #sequence length

    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size,
                      num_layers=num_layers, dropout=drop_prob,batch_first=True) #lstm
    # self.dropout = nn.Dropout(drop_prob)
    # self.fc_1 =  nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
    self.fc_1 =  nn.Linear(hidden_size, 64) #fully connected 1
    self.fc = nn.Linear(64, num_classes) #fully connected last layer

    self.relu = nn.ReLU()

def forward(self,x):
    # h_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)).to(device) #hidden state
    # c_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)).to(device) #internal state
    # Propagate input through LSTM
    output, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x) #lstm with input, hidden, and internal state
    
    hn = hn.view(-1, self.hidden_size) #reshaping the data for Dense layer next
    #out = self.dropout(hn)
    out = self.relu(hn)
    out = self.fc_1(out) #first Dense
    out = self.relu(out) #relu
    out = self.fc(out) #Final Output
    out = self.relu(out) #relu

    return out
```

My training data has these dimensions where the first one is the input and second the labels

`Training Shape torch.Size([8051, 1, 201]) torch.Size([8051, 1])`

When I  train with num_layers variable = 1 for the LSTM layer it works fine.
However, when I increase the num_layers to 2 I get the error which says

```
    Training Shape torch.Size([8051, 1, 201]) torch.Size([8051, 1])
Testing Shape torch.Size([4930, 1, 201]) torch.Size([4930, 1])
C:\Users\adity\miniconda3\envs\pytorch3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:528: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([8051, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([16102, 1])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adity\OneDrive - Louisiana State University\Documents\CSC 7343 HW\hw1.py", line 135, in <module>
    loss = criterion(outputs.to(device), y_train_tensors.to(device))
  File "C:\Users\adity\miniconda3\envs\pytorch3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adity\miniconda3\envs\pytorch3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 528, in forward
    return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "C:\Users\adity\miniconda3\envs\pytorch3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3089, in mse_loss
    expanded_input, expanded_target = torch.broadcast_tensors(input, target)
  File "C:\Users\adity\miniconda3\envs\pytorch3\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py", line 73, in broadcast_tensors
    return _VF.broadcast_tensors(tensors)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (16102) must match the size of tensor b (8051) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

When I changed layers to 3 the error says the size of tensor should be 24153.

Why is the input dimensions changing when I increase num_layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are flattening `hn`, according to the documentation page, its shape is `(D*num_layers, N, Hout)`, *i.e.* it depends on the number of hidden layers. So you will either have to change the fully connected that is following or only take the last hidden state of your LSTM.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. " So you will either have to change the fully-connected that is following or only take the last hidden state of your LSTM. " But I have no idea how to do either of those. 
Would increasing the input cells in fc layer work?

Comment: If you want to pass the entirety of the final hidden state then yes `fc1` must have `num_layers*hidden_size` neurons.

Comment: @lvan
 Thank you very much.
After reading this article about 10 times, I understood and all my models worked perfectly.